# Ubuntu software center not loading

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gnome-terminal

I have tried loading up the software center in order to install some packages but it doesn't seem to open. I tried entering the following command in terminal:

```
software-center
```

and get the following error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/software-center: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this out, `killall snap-store` then relaunch the app

Answer (score 1):

Try this, worked for me `sudo apt install gnome-software`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out some default package files for python were missing:

```
sudo apt-get -m --reinstall install python python-minimal dh-python
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ubuntu 20.04 with default configurations means you should ignore answers prompting you to explore gnome-software adjustments. This version uses the snap-store to manage applications. This worked for me.

```
    $ killall snap-store
    $ snap-store
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open all snap sofwares (including the software center) by just restarting the snapd service like this:

```
sudo service snapd restart
```

Or

```
sudo systemctl restart snapd
```